# apex detail page is blank

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I am trying to display detail of a custom object by using apex:detail. But i am getting no a blank page without any details i try it with Account but it was not working.

```
 <apex:page standardController="CustomObjectA__c">
   <apex:detail subject="{!CustomObjectA__c.id}" relatedList="true" title="false"/> 
 </apex:page>
```

please help me to get it solved.

Answer (score 4):

With a standard controller, `<apex:detail />` without a subject should be sufficient, but you must  pass an id to the page, e.g., `http://c.naX.visual.force.com/apex/detailTest?id=a03E00000082KUi`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you may not have a property in your controller to represent the specific CustomObjectA__c you are referencing.

Since you are using the standard controller, this can be done pretty easily.

**In your controller**

```
public class MyCustomExtension{

    public CustomObjectA__c myObject   {get;set;}

    public MyCustomExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.myObject= (CustomObjectA__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

}
```

**And adjust your VF to use your new property**

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObjectA__c" extensions="MyCustomExtension">
    <apex:detail subject="{!myObject.id}" relatedList="true" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: sfdc_ninja: you are missing the `extensions="MyCustomExtension"` from the apex:page line; however, I think Jason Clark has the real answer here

Answer (score 0):

For Standard Controller you need to Pass CustomObjectA__c object record Id in the URL...

i.e.,  /apex/page?id=RecordId

Answer (score -1):

Also, silly one but, the "id" in the query string is case sensitive.

Having that wrong (or some other typo in the query string parameters) will produce the same behaviour as you are receiving.